# Copy file from GCP Instance to GCP bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, gsutil

I follow the gsutil instructions to copy a local file on my gcp linux instance up to my bucket.

i run the command from the dir where the file is

gsutil -m cp -r gs://bucket_name/folder1/folder2 filename

I get these:

CommandException: Destination URL must name a directory, bucket, or bucket
subdirectory for the multiple source form of the cp command.
CommandException: Destination URL must name a directory, bucket, or bucket
subdirectory for the multiple source form of the cp command.
CommandException: 2 files/objects could not be transferred.

thanks

Comment: Where is the source, and where is the target for your “gsutil” command?

Comment: did you try to add a trailing slash or a star?

Answer (score 2):

Provided that **filename** is a local file that you want to copy to Cloud Storage, use this command:

```
gsutil -m cp filename gs://bucket_name/folder1/folder2
```

The `-r` command line option means **recursive** copy. You would not use that when specifying a single file. Your source and destination parameters were also reversed

Comment: John, that did it! Much appreciated! I'll look for gsutil examples to keep learning it.

Answer (score -2):

Please modify your command like below.

**gsutil -m cp filename gs://bucket_name/folder1/folder2**

It should work.